# Can I access different controls inside other formview controls?

Tags: asp.net

I have several forms, each with their own DDL, that I'm using inside a page. I have them in different forms because I need different data sources for each DDL. When I press the Submit button, it gives me an error that it can't find the control "ddlCategory". I assume it is because it is in a different formview control. Here is the markup:

```
<asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID" 
DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1" DefaultMode="Insert" >
<InsertItemTemplate>    
    Select a Category:<br />
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCategory" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"
        DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1" DataTextField="ORG_NAME" 
        DataValueField="ID">
    </asp:DropDownList>
</InsertItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
<asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource1" runat="server"
DataFile="~/App_Data/webvideos.mdb"
SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [ORGANIZATIONS]"/>
<br />
<asp:FormView ID="FormView2" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID" 
DataSourceID="AccessDataSource2" DefaultMode="Insert" >
<InsertItemTemplate>
    Select an Organization:<br />
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlOrg" runat="server"
        DataSourceID="AccessDataSource2" DataTextField="SectionName"
        DataValueField="ID">
    </asp:DropDownList>
</InsertItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>    
<asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource2" runat="server"
DataFile="~/App_Data/webvideos.mdb"
SelectCommand="SELECT ID,SectionName FROM ORG_SECTIONS WHERE OrgID=@OrgID ">
<SelectParameters>
    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlCategory"
        PropertyName="SelectedValue"
        Name="ID" Type="String"
        DefaultValue="" />
</SelectParameters>
</asp:AccessDataSource>
<br />
<asp:FormView ID="FormView3" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID" 
DataSourceID="AccessDataSource3" DefaultMode="Insert" >
<InsertItemTemplate>
    Select an Attorney:<br />
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAtty" runat="server" 
        DataSourceID="AccessDataSource3" DataTextField="Expr1" DataValueField="ATTY_ID">
    </asp:DropDownList>
</InsertItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
<asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource3" runat="server" 
DataFile="~/App_Data/webvideos.mdb" 
SelectCommand="SELECT ATTY_ID, NAME & ' ' & INITIAL & ' ' & LASTNAME AS Expr1 FROM ATTORNEYS ORDER BY NAME & INITIAL & ' ' & LASTNAME">
</asp:AccessDataSource>
```

Here is the code behind:

```
protected void AddRec(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList ddlCategory = (DropDownList)FormView1.FindControl("ddlCategory");
    DropDownList ddlOrg = (DropDownList)FormView2.FindControl("ddlOrg");
    DropDownList ddlAtty = (DropDownList)FormView3.FindControl("ddlAtty");

    string constr = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\webvideos.mdb;";
    string cmdstr = "INSERT INTO [Org_Sec_Atty] ([OrgID], [SecID], [AttyID]) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";


    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
    OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand(cmdstr, con);

    con.Open();
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrgID", ddlCategory.SelectedValue);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SecID", ddlOrg.SelectedValue);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AttyID", ddlAtty.SelectedValue);
    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    Response.Redirect("ManageProfAffs.aspx");
}
```

Again, it tells me that it can't find the control ddlCategory. I thought about putting them all in one formview, but how would I make different datasources for each of the dropdown lists? I also tried not having any formview controls at all and just using "this.[ID of the ddl]" but that gave me a null reference value. Any ideas on how to make this work?

Comment: What's the problem, why can't you use different datasources for different dropdownlists?

Comment: The DDLs will be inside the formview, which has its own datasource. Would I still be able to use different datasources? For instance, the formview control has datasource1, can I use datasource2 for my DDL inside the formview?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it. I ended up putting all the DDLs inside one formview (I didn't realize I could specify different datasources for DDLs within a formview that has its own datasource) and putting the datasource that uses the  property to use the value from the previous DDL. Works like a charm now.

```
<asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource1" runat="server"
    DataFile="~/App_Data/webvideos.mdb"
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [ORGANIZATIONS]"/>

<asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource3" runat="server" 
    DataFile="~/App_Data/webvideos.mdb" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT ATTY_ID, NAME & ' ' & INITIAL & ' ' & LASTNAME AS Expr1 FROM ATTORNEYS ORDER BY NAME & INITIAL & ' ' & LASTNAME">
</asp:AccessDataSource>
<br />
<asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID" 
    DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1" DefaultMode="Insert" >
    <InsertItemTemplate>    
        Select a Category:<br />
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCategory" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"
            DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1" DataTextField="ORG_NAME" 
            DataValueField="ID">
        </asp:DropDownList>
    <br />
    <asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource2" runat="server"
        DataFile="~/App_Data/webvideos.mdb"
        SelectCommand="SELECT ID,SectionName FROM ORG_SECTIONS WHERE OrgID=@OrgID ">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlCategory"
                PropertyName="SelectedValue"
                Name="ID" Type="String"
                DefaultValue="" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:AccessDataSource>
        Select an Organization:<br />
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlOrg" runat="server"
            DataSourceID="AccessDataSource2" DataTextField="SectionName"
            DataValueField="ID">
        </asp:DropDownList>
<br />
        Select an Attorney:<br />
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAtty" runat="server" 
            DataSourceID="AccessDataSource3" DataTextField="Expr1" DataValueField="ATTY_ID">
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </InsertItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
<br />
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="AddRec" />
```

And the code behind:

```
protected void AddRec(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList ddlCategory = (DropDownList)FormView1.FindControl("ddlCategory");
    DropDownList ddlOrg = (DropDownList)FormView1.FindControl("ddlOrg");
    DropDownList ddlAtty = (DropDownList)FormView1.FindControl("ddlAtty");

    string constr = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\webvideos.mdb;";
    string cmdstr = "INSERT INTO [Org_Sec_Atty] ([OrgID], [SecID], [Atty_ID]) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";


    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
    OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand(cmdstr, con);

    con.Open();
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrgID", ddlCategory.SelectedValue);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SecID", ddlOrg.SelectedValue);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AttyID", ddlAtty.SelectedValue);
    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    Response.Redirect("ManageProfAffs.aspx");
}
```